# Slick Database Instantiation And Connection Pool Logic

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am instantiating a slick database with code similar to

```
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database

val db : Database =  Database forConfig "configPath"
```

The query is constructed from a function that takes in a user id and returns a user name from the database table:

```
def queryName(userId : String) =
  for {
    row <- TableQuery[Tables.MyTable] if row.userid === userId
  } yield row.username
```

And then running the query to produce distinct `Publisher` values:

```
val p1 : Publisher[String] = db stream (queryName("foo").result)

val p2 : Publisher[String] = db stream (queryName("bar").result)
```

Finally, my question is: **Do multiple calls to `db.stream` utilize the same connection in the connection pool?**

In other words, once I've instantiated the database is that the same as locking in on a single connection?

The implication would be that true utilization of all connections in the pool would require a function to create `Database` values before querying:

```
//Is this necessary?

val db = () => Database forConfig "configPath"

val p1 = db() stream (queryName("foo").result)
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Slick documentation about [database thread pool](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html?highlight=pool#database-thread-pool):

> When using `Database.forConfig`, the thread pool is configured directly in the external configuration file together with the connection parameters.

My hypothesis here is that you are using a connection pool (which is always recommended in production environments) and you have configured it properly in the external configuration file (the one referred by `configPath`).

You don't have to worry about database connections since your `Database` object (your `db`) is managing that for you.

Each call to `db.stream()` actually uses (and withdraw) a connection from the pool (eventually opening a new one according to the pool size and configuration) and releases it afterwards back into the pool.

For further details on how a connection pool works and how to configure (e.g. size) it in slick can be found at [connection-pools](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html#connection-pools).

An addictional note from [adding-slick-to-your-project](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html#adding-slick-to-your-projec):

> If you want to use Slick’s connection pool support, you need to add HikariCP as a dependency.